# how to check if the class behaves correctly when the list contains even and odd numbers using Junit

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have a problem with assertion in my code: I don't know how can I check if the class behaves correctly when the list contains even and odd numbers.

Main Method:

```
public class OddNumbersExterminator {

    public ArrayList<Integer> exterminate(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
        ArrayList<Integer> oddNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> evenNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int number : numbers) {
            if(number % 2 == 0)
            {
                oddNumbers.add(number);
            } else {
                evenNumbers.add(number);
            }
        }
        return oddNumbers;
    }
```

Testing method:

```
@Test
public void testOddNumbersExterminatorNormalList() {
    //Given
    OddNumbersExterminator oddNumbersExterminator = new OddNumbersExterminator();
    ArrayList<Integer> normalList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    normalList.add(1);
    normalList.add(2);
    normalList.add(3);
    normalList.add(4);
    normalList.add(5);
    normalList.add(6);
    //When

    //Then
}
```

Comment: Why does your `exterminate` put all the even numbers into a list that is then discarded?

Comment: It was so in the task content that it would return only odd numbers

Comment: What khelwood is trying to say - you can toss away your `evenNumbers`. In your current code you fill it but you never use it.

Comment: Actually I misread your code. You're actually putting all the **odd** numbers in a list called `evenNumbers` which is then discarded.

Comment: I think your variables are named incorrectly in the `exterminate()` method. You should switch the lists (names) so that you return `evenNumbers` instead (= the result of adding only even ones from the original). Just more clearer that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
    OddNumbersExterminator oddNumbersExterminator = new OddNumbersExterminator();
    ArrayList<Integer> normalList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    normalList.add(1);
    normalList.add(2);
    normalList.add(3);
    normalList.add(4);
    normalList.add(5);
    normalList.add(6);

    List<Integer> actualResult = oddNumbersExterminator.exterminate(normalList);
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6), actualResult);
```

Comment: Your assertion is the same as production code, it's better to make them different. Why not simply `assertEquals(asList(1, 3, 5), result)`?

Comment: Ok, but how can I get it without 'stream'?

Comment: @Tom99 check above Stanislav comment

Comment: expected:<[2, 4, 6]> but was:<[]>
Expected :[2, 4, 6]
Actual   :[]
<Click to see difference>

java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[2, 4, 6]> but was:<[]>
 at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)

Comment: This means that your code doesn't works well. `actualResult` is empty while it should contains odd numbers assuming code from yours question